# Sql database query without the server side scripting

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hey. I want to write a sql query for a table:

```
user_1(question_id int, option char(1));
```

Here, in this table, I am having `question_id` arranged randomly and client will send the previous `question_id` to the server. Then, I need the next `question_id` in table coming after the `question_id` sent by client.

I can do this with the server side scripting but is it possible without that? I mean directly having the next `question_id` with sql.

Sample Data:

```
4, 'A'
2, 'B'
7, 'C'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no way of determining which question should go next.
If you query a table without any order specified it might look like you have a set of rows ordered by time of insert. While this is true for small tables you should not rely on it. Any fair amount of record inserting/deleting or doing table analyze can change this order and you end up with your order being wrong.
If you don't have any other column keeping order at which you inserted data there is completely no guarantee you will get it right after doing select without order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...

```
SELECT MIN(question_id) FROM user_1 WHERE question_id > (value client sent)
```

Comment: but question_id is arranged randomly.

Comment: @codeomnitrix - If the next question isn't the the next consecutive ID, how do you know which one it is? Maybe you should add a `question_order` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from question 
where id not in (already asked)
order by rand()
limit 0,1
```

**edit**: Seeing updated question, the answer is - no way. You need some other field that will set the order of the questions, because there's no way to tell now what order they come in.

You should think about database table as about UNORDERED record set.

Comment: hey can't understand. first i am not having the records of previously asked questions. just of last question nothing else. And also can't understand what this query will do??

Comment: It will return a single id of a random question (ordered by random numbers). You can leave off the part `where id not in (...)`. Or do you wish to use some other way of randomization? Er, updated my answer.

Comment: i think you haven't understood my problem. please see the sample data. actually the question_id is already randomized so no need to use random function. i just want the next unused question from randomly arranged questions.

Comment: Oh yes. It's completely not the way things are done. First, to randomize questions you don't update their `id`s in database - you rather select a question with random `id`. Second, you need some mean to identify a record (order) in a table - you don't have such now.